# Loading screen while List is rendering - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-developer

I am fetching some videos from an API, and made an animated loading screen that shows while the data is being fetched. After the data is recieved, i want to show the vidoes in a list. It takes quite a long time to "render" the videos in the list, and the loading screen stops after the data is fetched.

Is there a way to show the loading screen while Swift "makes" the list-page in the background?

Here is my code:

```swiftUI
import SwiftUI

struct ListExample: View {
    @State var loaded: Bool = false
    @State var serverData2 = ServerMessage(SavedClips: [], SentryClips: [])
    @State var SavedClips2: Array<String> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            if loaded {
                    List(self.SavedClips2, id: \.self) { string in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailedVideo(url: string)) {
                            VideShow(url: string, thumbnail: string)
                        }
                    }
                
                                }
            else {
                LoadingPage()
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            self.manager.postAuth(car_name: self.name) { (posts) in
                self.serverData2 = posts
                self.loaded = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestFile_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to show the screen during loading of the view, not only during the request?

Comment: Yes that's right @davidev. It takes longer time to load the view than the request.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of VideoShow.